# Carousel view implementation like listview scrolling

Tags: android, carousel, android-custom-view

Anyone has implemented like the below `carousel`?
Note: The list of items should not be repeated, means should not come to first after reaching the last item. Please help me on this.

[image: carousel listview]

[edited]

[image]

I don't want to use ListView for this.
anyone help me on this. Thanks...

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

Comment: did you make that project? I need vertical one, can you share some sample code?

Comment: @mustafa use the below Renard solution for vertical one.

Comment: @noundla please forgive me but I dont understand where do I use those codes which shared by Renard. The thing what I want to do is exactly same the first picture you mentioned above and I need that very urgent. You mentioned the codes or sony's sample project for a solution?

Comment: @noundla any idea about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417882/list-view-with-change-width-of-row-when-scroll-android ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should get you started. Override your ListView like so:

```
private final Transformation mTransformation;

public ListView3d(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true);
        mTransformation = new Transformation();
        mTransformation.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
    } else {
        mTransformation = null;
    }       
}

@Override
protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
    mTransformation.getMatrix().reset();
    final int childTop = Math.max(0,child.getTop());
    final int parentHeight = getHeight();
    final float scale = (float)(parentHeight-(childTop/2))/getHeight();
    Log.i("scale",scale+"");
    final float px = child.getLeft() + (child.getWidth()) / 2;
    final float py = child.getTop() + (child.getHeight()) / 2;
    mTransformation.getMatrix().postScale(scale, scale, px, py);
    t.compose(mTransformation);
    return true;
}
```

in getChildStaticTransformation you can achieve various effects (even 3d) by manipulating the matrix accordingly. 
A very good tutorial (which uses another technique can be found [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/).

Comment: By the above listview items are getting some space between one another  based on the position. but i dont need that, so how can i remove that space..

Comment: @Renard how can i achieved this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417882/list-view-with-change-width-of-row-when-scroll-android ?

Answer (score 1):

this can be achieved using a custom list view. Using an adapter in a listactivity will make it possible. a look [here](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/custom-listview-android) will make it clearer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can to try that carousel with RecycleView. Link : [Carousel DemoProject](https://github.com/DimaKoz/CarouselExample)