# Android: vertical 3d listview

Tags: android, listview, 3d, imagebutton

I would like to make vertical 3d list view [like here](http://www.binpress.com/app/3d-listview-for-android/725), but for ImageButtons and for free. Is there any library or sample code for that? I am new in Android development, so I don't know how to animate such thing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

its actually pretty simple. You need to extend ListView and override onDrawChild(). In there you can apply 3d transformation matrices to get the effect you want. 
I have  a working example on my [github](https://github.com/renard314/ListView3d)
Or you can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942443/carousel-view-implementation-like-listview-scrolling/9942951#9942951) which is quite similar.

For your convenience this is my implementation of a 3d ListView:

```
public class ListView3d extends ListView {

    /** Ambient light intensity */
    private static final int AMBIENT_LIGHT = 55;
    /** Diffuse light intensity */
    private static final int DIFFUSE_LIGHT = 200;
    /** Specular light intensity */
    private static final float SPECULAR_LIGHT = 70;
    /** Shininess constant */
    private static final float SHININESS = 200;
    /** The max intensity of the light */
    private static final int MAX_INTENSITY = 0xFF;

    private final Camera mCamera = new Camera();
    private final Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    /** Paint object to draw with */
    private Paint mPaint;

    public ListView3d(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean drawChild(Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
        // get top left coordinates
        final int top = child.getTop();
        final int left = child.getLeft();
        Bitmap bitmap = child.getDrawingCache();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            child.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            child.buildDrawingCache();
            bitmap = child.getDrawingCache();
        }

        final int centerY = child.getHeight() / 2;
        final int centerX = child.getWidth() / 2;
        final int radius = getHeight() / 2;
        final int absParentCenterY = getTop() + getHeight() / 2;
        final int absChildCenterY = child.getTop() + centerX;
        final int distanceY = absParentCenterY - absChildCenterY;
        final int absDistance = Math.min(radius, Math.abs(distanceY));

        final float translateZ = (float) Math.sqrt((radius * radius) - (absDistance * absDistance));

        double radians = Math.acos((float) absDistance / radius);
        double degree = 90 - (180 / Math.PI) * radians;

        mCamera.save();
        mCamera.translate(0, 0, radius - translateZ);
        mCamera.rotateX((float) degree); // remove this line..
        if (distanceY < 0) {
            degree = 360 - degree;
        }
        mCamera.rotateY((float) degree); // and change this to rotateX() to get a
                                            // wheel like effect
        mCamera.getMatrix(mMatrix);
        mCamera.restore();

        // create and initialize the paint object
        if (mPaint == null) {
            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        }
        //highlight elements in the middle
        mPaint.setColorFilter(calculateLight((float) degree));

        mMatrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
        mMatrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
        mMatrix.postTranslate(left, top);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);
        return false;
    }

    private LightingColorFilter calculateLight(final float rotation) {
        final double cosRotation = Math.cos(Math.PI * rotation / 180);
        int intensity = AMBIENT_LIGHT + (int) (DIFFUSE_LIGHT * cosRotation);
        int highlightIntensity = (int) (SPECULAR_LIGHT * Math.pow(cosRotation, SHININESS));
        if (intensity > MAX_INTENSITY) {
            intensity = MAX_INTENSITY;
        }
        if (highlightIntensity > MAX_INTENSITY) {
            highlightIntensity = MAX_INTENSITY;
        }
        final int light = Color.rgb(intensity, intensity, intensity);
        final int highlight = Color.rgb(highlightIntensity, highlightIntensity, highlightIntensity);
        return new LightingColorFilter(light, highlight);
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: When I try to download your project through Git, Eclipse can't find any projects in there. I tried downloading as Zip and directly from git. The same issue. Also tried to configure your project, but there goes lots of errors

Comment: I dont like to have project files in my repositories. But this should be no problem as you can simply do the following: 1. download as zip. 2. Extract to a folder of your choice. 3. In eclipse do new->Android Project->Create Project from existing source. 4. Set Build target to android 4 or remove hardwareacceleration from the manifest. Maybe you also need to clean the project..

Comment: With some corrections, I got your code to work, but there is another problem: how to change position to selected row? also, how to make rows to overlay each other. Like here: [link](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/1375/snor1.jpg)

Comment: ListView.setSelection(int) will scroll to a position of your choice. For the overlap you can use mMatrix to position the child views.

Comment: You can change the drawing order the children with setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled() and overriding getChildDrawingOrder(). This way you should manage to get the correct  overlap( draw order is basically dependent on the z-value). As for the space between rows you can try to increase the padding or margin in the  layout-xml for the child-views.

Comment: How change overlap to below center rows? I changed translate z axis, so it looks like overlapping, but all rows overlaps each other going down. So last row is always on top and first row is always on bottom (Seeing as layers)

Comment: Overlap is dependent on drawing order so you need to override getChildDrawingOrder() and specify that the items wich have the largest z-translation are drawn first

Comment: Is there any way to preserve the transparency of the view when using this 3d list view? beacuse my view background is not semi transprent.

Comment: A small correction, this ==> "final int absChildCenterY = child.getTop() + centerX;" should be " + centerY"

Comment: How to start reverse the animation from top to bottom?