# Android: Vertical ListView with overlapped rows

Tags: java, android, listview, carousel

How to create listview like this in android 1.6 or 2 (because of renderscript, which works only in 3 or later, but I need list to work on almost all androids):

[image]

Comment: Any ideas how to approach that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used `Camera.setTranslate(x, 0, z)` in drawChild, where changed x position for rotation virtualization and z for overlaping. Then there was problem with overlapping, because last item was on top and first on bottom layer. So, in `onCreate()` method called `this.setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true)` and overriden `protected int getChildDrawingOrder (int childCount, int i) {}` where I could change order for middle and later rows.
This idea was given by Renard, who suggested me in other my post about almost same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025270/android-vertical-3d-listview).

My getChildDrawingOrder(int, int) implementation to get overlapping I need:

```
@Override
protected int getChildDrawingOrder (int childCount, int i) {
    int centerChild = 0;
    //find center row
    if ((childCount % 2) == 0) { //even childCount number
        centerChild = childCount / 2; // if childCount 8 (actualy 0 - 7), then 4 and 4-1 = 3 is in centre.      
        int otherCenterChild = centerChild - 1;
        //Which more in center?
        View child = this.getChildAt(centerChild);
        final int top = child.getTop();
        final int bottom = child.getBottom();
        //if this row goes through center then this
        final int absParentCenterY = getTop() + getHeight() / 2;
        //Log.i("even", i + " from " + (childCount - 1) + ", while centerChild = " + centerChild);
        if ((top < absParentCenterY) && (bottom > absParentCenterY)) {
            //this child is in center line, so it is last
            //centerChild is in center, no need to change
        } else {
            centerChild = otherCenterChild;
        }
    }
    else {//not even - done
        centerChild = childCount / 2;
        //Log.i("not even", i + " from " + (childCount - 1) + ", while centerChild = " + centerChild);
    }

    int rez = i;
    //find drawIndex by centerChild
    if (i > centerChild) {
        //below center
        rez = (childCount - 1) - i + centerChild;
    } else if (i == centerChild) {
        //center row
        //draw it last
        rez = childCount - 1;
    } else {
        //above center - draw as always
        // i < centerChild
        rez = i;
    }
    //Log.i("return", "" + rez);
    return rez;

}
```

I hope this post will help someone in future

Screenshot is actually almost the same as I mentioned in my question. I used alpha, so overlayed items is a little bit see-through:

[image]

Comment: @pengwang what demo? you mean screenshot of result?

Comment: yes，you are right, can you share your screenshot of the result code

Comment: @PooLaS please give me preference link or post your classs to understand the this thing to implement.

Comment: Can you explain how you "used" Camera.setTranslate(x, 0, z)

Comment: hi @PooLaS can u share the complete sample code for this

Comment: he might have got the code from this repository: [CoverFlow](https://github.com/YiChaoLove/CoverFlow)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have source any more for a very long time. And no, I didn't use any other repo at the time, had to come up myself with some help from other devs