# Animated vertical sliding menu in android

Tags: android, menu, android-animation, sliding

I need to make a sliding vertical menu in android as below. user slide the screen to up or down for selecting related item and the selected item must be bigger than the other items. How can I do that in android? Any idea would be great.

[image]

Edit:

I'm very desperate and need some help. how to do this in android?
http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/uitableview-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

This can probably be achieved by using the `Camera.setTranslate` function.  See [Android: Vertical ListView with overlaped rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211835/android-vertical-listview-with-overlaped-rows) and [Android: vertical 3d listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025270/android-vertical-3d-listview) for similar questions (with solutions)