# List view with custom view items with partially overlaps (Android)

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

I want to implement a list in Android that contains some customized views.
My problem is that I want the the views will be put one after the other with a little overlap between them. like in the following schema: [image]

I also want to control this overlap in such a way that when the user clicks on one of the items, they will move apart from each other.

I tried to extend ListView but it seems to be very obscured, any suggestions?

Edit:
This can be more clear:

[image]

I did it by setting the divider height to -50dp.
this is exactly what I want to achieve, but somehow it doesn't reflect on my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by using scroll view with a single relative layout as a child.
I then dynamically place the views by defining a rule and margin:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("Text \n Text" + i);

        tv.setBackgroundColor(i % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        lp.leftMargin = 0;
        lp.topMargin = (i * 45);
        rl.addView(tv, lp);
}
```

Later, you can control the positioning of the sub-views by changing their y value (for example: if you want to add animation).

This is the final result:

[image: Layout containing overlapping items]

Comment: ScrollView doesn't support view recycling. So, if performance is a factor, it's pretty useless for several views.

Comment: I've implemented views recycling for my ScrollView based view.

Comment: @DanielL.would you please like to share your code on github or anywhere you like?

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be achieved by using the `Camera.setTranslate` function.  See [Android: Vertical ListView with overlaped rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10211835/android-vertical-listview-with-overlaped-rows) and [Android: vertical 3d listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025270/android-vertical-3d-listview) for similar questions (with solutions)