# Overlap first position view by second position in android scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview

Inside ScrollView I am adding textview dynamically to look like list view but now on scroll I want first position textview to be overlap by second or next textview item.

ref: [List view with custom view items with partially overlaps (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551501/list-view-with-custom-view-items-with-partially-overlaps-android)