# Android RecyclerView overlap items (Card stacks)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overlap

How can I overlap items in RecyclerView?
Like stacking cards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you done this? I need the same view

Comment: @DenisNek: Sorry, no. Since the LayoutManager approach is not easy, I still use the ListView to do it.

Comment: @denis Nak did you get anything for this i'm also having the same problem

Comment: https://github.com/amyu/StackCardLayoutManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write your own LayoutManager or extends LinearLayoutManager

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you provide any idea to start with?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/recyclerview/src/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java

You should start with reading the source of `LinearLayoutManager`, actually you would need to modify most of the code at the end. I believe You can start with copying the whole source code as your own `CardStackLayoutManager`, and try editing `onLayoutChildren`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: I found that difficult to extend or modify the LinearLayoutManager. Looking for another easier approach.

Comment: Yes, it is not easy to make LayoutManager. Maybe you can try just to fake it by some drawings, e.g. have each item add a child as the top part of the item below

Answer (score 17):

To overlap recyclerView rows, you can use this.

Add this class to your activity. You can customize the vertOverlap.

```
   public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final static int vertOverlap = -40;

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets (Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (itemPosition == 0) {
            return; }
        outRect.set(0, vertOverlap, 0, 0);


    }
} `
```

After that add your decoration to recyclerView before setting its layout manager, and we are done.

```
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlapDecoration());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Thanks to the @MojoTosh
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29067942/6255073

Comment: I have reply the solution and there is a problem: It has a strange behavior that only show items that can be draw entirely. It won't show the top-part of the next item below the bottom most one.

Comment: @shiami Could you explain it explicitly? A screenshot of your current problem maybe.
In my case first row stays same and other rows are overlapping properly

Comment: To overlap all items you can remove `if (itemPosition == 0` cause it is useless if you have padding/margin in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

**opsenes** answer works great! But I added a percentage calculation instead of a fixed value so that it can work for multiple devices and screens.

```
class ItemDecorator() : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
        if (position != 0) {
            val widthOverlapPercentage = 0.25
            val previousView = parent[position - 1]
            val overlapWidth = previousView.width * widthOverlapPercentage
         outRect.left = overlapWidth.toInt() * -1
        }
    }
}
```

My solution is based on a **horizontal** `RecyclerView`, so if you want to implement **Vertical**, just switch `previousView.width` with `previousView.height`, and `outRect.left` with `outRect.top`.
You can also set the percentage of the overlapping where 0 is no overlap, and 1 is full overlap.