# Recyclerview items as a stack

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

Is it possible to create android `Recyclerview` items as a stack. More than one items need to come under the top item.Also need to see the stack items on the bottom of the previous item.

```
public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                                   RecyclerView parent,
                                   RecyclerView.State state) {
            final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            if (itemPosition == 0) {
                return;
            }
            outRect.set(0, -150, 0, 0);
        }

    }

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlappDecoration());
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32319541/android-recyclerview-overlap-items-card-stacks

Comment: @Gaurav Mall - I have tried this, but actually I need to show the items on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack items from bottom using

```
LinearLayoutmanager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

and provide `bottom` margin in your decorator instead `top` margin

```
public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view,
                                   RecyclerView parent,
                                   RecyclerView.State state) {
            final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            if (itemPosition == 0) {
                return;
            }
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, -150);//<-- bottom
        }

    }

recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlappDecoration());
recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
```

Comment: Thank you, also is it possible to reduce the size(width) of the items?

Comment: you can do it in item layout itself