# Overlap items in recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overlapping

I have a RecyclerView with list of items displayed top to bottom.
I would like to have view of last item overlapping with the previous one.

I used `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` with negative top margin and it almost does the trick. Item views indeed overlap, but when I'm at the bottom of the list and I start scrolling up then overlapping view disappears too early.
It looks like RecyclerView does not take into account the negative margin at all when deciding if item is visible or not.

Is there a way to fix that?
Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Please provide a visual example of what you strive to achieve or have achieved with negative top margin. It will make it easier for others to suggest implementations.

Also, does this do the trick? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39216610/6835732

Comment: Thanks @PrimožIvančič I used the same approach as described in your link.
Also I added video showing the issue.

Comment: Do you want **all** of the items to overlap, or just the last one? In any case, using different layouts based on whether it needs to appear overlapped or not, might do the trick.