# RecyclerView reverse CardStack

Tags: android

Not entire sure if this is possible, but I'm implementing a "CardStack" effect from [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633454/how-to-overlap-items-in-linearlayoutmanager-recyclerview-like-stacking-cards) with my own custom `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` class. I noticed that the overlapping item is drawn such that RecyclerView item at position 0 is at the bottom,following by 1, 2, 3..etc.

Is there a reversed way such that item at position 0 is at the top most?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could use [setStackFromBottom](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setStackFromBottom(boolean)) and then in your adapter override `getItem` to return the items in reverse order. Your view should draw from the bottom up but the items will remain in the same order.

Comment: To clarify, I set the LinearManager to have `setStackFromEnd` and `setReverseLayout` as both true, then reverse the binding index in my adapter.