# Item overlap in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout, linearlayoutmanager

I want to overlap first item on second item in recycler view .

**this is what I want to achieve:**

[image: view that i'm trying to achieve]

**this is how my recycler view is looking now:**

[[image: this is what i'm getting]]

content inside green border is actually a recyclerView  and the first item in parent recycler view and the rating bar layout is the second item in parent recyclerview . 
please suggest me how can i overlap first item on to second item 
i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677024/recyclerview-overlap-items-bottom-to-top)

item_rating_layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/LayoutHeightWrapWidthMatchStyling"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_large">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRatingMessage"
            style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge"
            android:text="@string/rating_exp" />

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/gray"
            android:stepSize="1.0"
            android:progressTint="@color/primaryColor"
            android:rating="2.5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWriteFeedBack"
            style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXXLarge.primary"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
            android:text="Write Feedback"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

item_recycler_view:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_24dp"
        android:background="@color/warranty_card_background">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_shap_without_solid_green"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProductImage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_original_placeholder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge.black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tool:text="Steelbird Air" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvModel"
                        style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge"
                        tool:text="SBA-2 Horn Matt Black With Red " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvId"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge.gray"
                    android:text="@string/product_id" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvViewProductDetails"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XLarge.primary"
                    android:text="View product Details" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvWarrantyCard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Having items overlap is rather tricky. Can't you just add a bit of blue background on bottom of first item to mimick the behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow fix my problem by just adding a bit of same color as rating bar background on bottom of first item.

now here is the final xml look alike:

**item_recycler_view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llOverlapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/rating_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_24dp"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_shap_without_solid_green"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivProductImage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_original_placeholder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge.black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tool:text="Steelbird Air" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvModel"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge"
                    tool:text="SBA-2 Horn Matt Black With Red " />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvId"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XXLarge.gray"
                    android:text="@string/product_id" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvViewProductDetails"
                    style="@style/TextStyleNormal.XLarge.primary"
                    android:text="View product Details" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvWarrantyCard"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_medium"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium">

                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Big thank to @Pawel**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following ItemDecoration:

```
  public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

  private final static int vertOverlap = -90;

  @Override
  public void getItemOffsets (Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {

    outRect.set(0, vertOverlap, 0, 0);

  }
}
```

Now when you add the above decoration your next row will be drawn over your previous row. To rectify this make your recyclerview as reverse by using `setReverseLayout(true)`

You can refer to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40972877/5260051) which has almost same requirement

Answer (score 0):

Use main layout Relative otherwise Frame layout