# How to make recycleView Items intersected?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make the views inside horizontal recycleView to be intersected by each other with some percentage like this image.
what is the  best approach of doing this?

[image: overlapping images]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Overlap items in LinearLayoutManager - RecyclerView (like stacking cards)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633454/how-to-overlap-items-in-linearlayoutmanager-recyclerview-like-stacking-cards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I erased the wrong answer, this one work perfectly.

You need to create the following class(it can be inner class if you are gone use of in one activity).

```
public class OverlapDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final static int horizontalOverlap = -100;

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        final int itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
        if (itemPosition == 0) { return; }
        outRect.set(horizontalOverlap, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Then you add an Item Decoration to your recyclerView.

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new OverlapDecoration());
```

Comment: I set it to 100 pixels (also tried horizontal) but the output was the same as in this photo
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxMISdowfennM25hbndOck9MSFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I change the answer now it might work exactly like you want.