# Layered Image View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image: View That I Wanted]

I want To Create Image Thumb Like Above..
For This I Created XML Below

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">


      <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"    
            android:background="@drawable/images1">
        </View>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/images1">
        </View>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/images1">
        </View>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But This Which I Created Is Manually Added In XML. And May Be It Will React Different in Different device Type. 
Is There Any Other Way To Create This Type Of View..

Any Help Accepted.

Thank You.

Comment: I think this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038542/recyclerview-horizontal-deck-of-cards-effect/43487236 . Change the code accordingly and give margins if possible

Comment: thank you For Link.. but It Is worked For Flat Base.. I need Layered View.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your idea is fine. You are using `dp` as size units so `Views` will look similarly on different devices.
The only thing I can propose as an improvement - move all this stuff to separate `View` class:

```
class ThumbView extends RelativeLayout {
    private ImageView vLayer1;
    private ImageView vLayer2;
    private ImageView vLayer3;

    public ThumbView(Context context, String pathToFile) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
          .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_thumb, this, true);
        vLayer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.view1);
        vLayer2 = view.findViewById(R.id.view2);
        vLayer3 = view.findViewById(R.id.view3);

        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(pathToFile);

        vLayer1.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        vLayer2.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        vLayer3.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

I assume that you are going to use files from gallery for the thumbs so added path to file to constructor. So it will be easier to create these views from code.

Another approach that you can use for this purpose is drawing of `Bitmaps` directly on `Canvas`. This way can provide some performance advantages if you suppose to create a great amount of such views (to show them for example in List/Grid).
Please follow this [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) for more details.

Comment: yes, creating different class is good Idea.. But My Xml Is From Adapter Class Which is Shown In List View.. Is This Valid To Create That Kind Of Class For Adapter (Sorry For Incomplete Info. in Question)

Comment: and yes the thumb image was from gallery or camera

Comment: in Adapter you can do without any additional class. In getView() you already have something like view = yourInflater.inflate(...). So you have just to put images to the layers as described above.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this custom view.

> LayeredImageView.java

```
public class LayeredImageView extends RelativeLayout {
    private final int offset = 50;
    private int offsetMargin = offset;
    private int count = 0;
    private int imageHeight = 600;
    private int imageWidth = 600;
    private Context context;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public LayeredImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public LayeredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public LayeredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public void addImage(int res) {
        count++;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, res));
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                imageWidth,
                imageHeight);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        params.setMargins(offsetMargin, offsetMargin, 0, 0);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(imageView);
        this.invalidate();
        offsetMargin += offset;
    }

    public void setImageHeight(int imageHeight) {
        this.imageHeight = imageHeight;
    }

    public void setImageWidth(int imageWidth) {
        this.imageWidth = imageWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawForeground(Canvas canvas) {
        for (int o = offset, i = 0; i < count; o += offset, i++) {
            canvas.drawRect(o, o, imageWidth + o, imageHeight + o, paint);
        }
        super.onDrawForeground(canvas);
    }
}
```

The view contains some hardcoded values which you can change depending on your needs.

Then in your activity or fragment inflate the layout and add the images dynamically

```
LayeredImageView view = (LayeredImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
view.addImage(R.drawable.img_1);
view.addImage(R.drawable.img_2);
view.addImage(R.drawable.img_3);
```

> DEMO

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For overlapping views, **FrameLayout** is the exact container you should use as it is built for this purpose. FrameLayout stacks child views one on the other with the most recently added one on the top. The **z-index depends on the order of the child views**. In the layout below, *view3* will be above *view2* and *view2* will be above *view1*.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/images1">
    </View>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/images1">
    </View>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/images1">
    </View>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and pase below code FrameLayout is specially designed for this purpose 
here below is Root Layout is **FrameLayout** then

**Imageview** one after Another

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
</ImageView>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview3"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">
</ImageView> </FrameLayout>
```

try this and let me know please

Answer (score 0):

Use a `frame layout` and use `marginLeft` and `marginTop` in increasing order for each `image view`.
You can use a library to provide margin dimensions in order to get a responsive output.

https://github.com/intuit/sdp

You can even add `image views` with different margins to `frame layout` programatically using a loop. This will allow you to add any number of `image views` according to your input.

Comment: sorry,I did Not Understand what you want To Say.

Answer (score -1):

use this code ...

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_thumb, this, true);
            viewLayer1 = view.findViewById(R.id.view1);
            viewLayer2 = view.findViewById(R.id.view2);
            viewLayer3 = view.findViewById(R.id.view3);
    Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(pathToFile);

            viewLayer1.setImageDrawable("@drawable/images1");
            viewLayer2.setImageDrawable("@drawable/images1");
            viewLayer3.setImageDrawable("@drawable/images1");
```

your problem must be solved