# Overlapping items in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view

I am trying to make a pseudo 3d ListView in which each item overlaps other something like a card stack (see below).

[image: card stack listview]

I have overridden ListView's drawChild method, in which I am doing some translation stuffs & have achieved above. Now problem is that ListView is only showing the items that were visible without the offsetting.

How can I tell ListView to adjust for the room created by offsetting the items ?

My implementation is:

```
@Override
protected boolean drawChild(final Canvas canvas, final View child, final long drawingTime) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getChildDrawingCache(child);   

    // center point of child
    final int childCenterY = child.getHeight() / 2;

    //center of list
    final int parentCenterY = getHeight() / 2;

    //center point of child relative to list
    final int absChildCenterY = child.getTop() + childCenterY;

    //distance of child center to the list center
    final int distanceY = parentCenterY - absChildCenterY;

    //radius of imaginary cirlce
    final int r = getHeight() / 2;

    if (mMatrix == null) {
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
    }

    prepareMatrix(mMatrix, distanceY, r, child.getHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, mMatrix, mPaint);

    return false;
}

private void prepareMatrix(final Matrix outMatrix, float distanceY, float r, float heightChild){
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    mCamera.save();

    float visibility = ((distanceY/r) * (2*heightChild/3));

    mCamera.getMatrix(outMatrix);

    outMatrix.setTranslate(0, (heightChild - visibility));

    mCamera.restore();
}

private Bitmap getChildDrawingCache(final View child){
    Bitmap bitmap = child.getDrawingCache();
    if (bitmap == null) {
        child.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        child.buildDrawingCache();
        bitmap = child.getDrawingCache();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

I have already gone through:

- [Making your own 3D list](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2010/05/31/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-2/)
- [Android: vertical 3d listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025270/android-vertical-3d-listview)

But could not find solution for there.

Comment: Alternate idea: What about configuring an `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: I would like to animate cards while scrolling

Comment: @Varun do you get any idea for that how to implement this type of list view

Comment: @SameerDonga Google introduced [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) for these kind of listviews. Go through [this tutorial](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/) for its implementation.