# How do I do this in android?

Tags: android, slide, swipe, swipe-gesture

http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/uitableview-tricks/

I'm very desperate and need some help. give me idea please!

Comment: Is this an Android question or an iPhone question?  Regardless, what IS your question?

Comment: there is an Iphone sample above, I need to do it in android and I can not find any solution about how do I do it in android. I need just some idea. Not want tutorials or any shit, just idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very similar to [Carousel view implementation like listview scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942443/carousel-view-implementation-like-listview-scrolling) and by the way this is just a "carousel view/layout", i find it very unusable.